# Ball Probability help

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

A bowl contains 5 red balls, 3 white balls and 2 blue balls. Two balls are seleceted at random from the bowl (without replacement).

- **A)** What is the probability that both are red? which is 2/9
- **B)** What is the probability that the 2 balls are the same color? whcih is 14/45
- **C)** What is the probability that the 2 balls are different color?

I found A and B but can't find C. Not sure how to set up this one.

Comment: There's a standard 'trick' for questions like this. Hint: what's the probability that the two balls are not different colours?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Either they are the same color, or they are different color.  So
$$
\mathbb{P}[\text{same color}] + \mathbb{P}[\text{different color}] = ?
$$

You already know what is $\mathbb{P}[\text{same color}]$ from (B).

Comment: would it be (10*9)/2*1 = 45?  @gt6989b

Comment: @user3335209 from (B) you found $\mathbb{P}[\text{same color}] = 14/45$. They must be either same or different, so $$\mathbb{P}[\text{same color}] + \mathbb{P}[\text{different color}] = 1$$

Comment: Ok thank you @gt6989b

Answer (score 1):

To find C, subtract B from $1$ is the easiest way. Otherwise, you can list the three pairs of different colors, calculate the chance of each, and add.